# How to Disable Automatic Killed on Centos Server using Webuzo

Tags: mysql, apache, centos

I have some problems but sometimes my vps auto down, whenever httpd, apache, or mysql
sometimes I must restart my webuzo using

```
service webuzo restart
```

so I can see my site live again.

Why am I having this problem? Is server automatically down because of high used resource?

If so, how can I make command shell autogenerate command service restart?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Execute the following command and it should be running on reboot

// On CentOS
Root > chkconfig webuzo on

// On Ubuntu
Root > update-rc.d webuzo defaults

Hope it helps